# Using CONTAINS from HQL / Criteria API

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, full-text-search, hql, criteria

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000GA. I'm trying to use SQL Server's `CONTAINS` function from within HQL and the criteria APIs. This works fine in HQL:

```
CONTAINS(:value)
```

However, I need to qualify the table in question. This works fine:

```
CONTAINS(table.Column, :value)
```

However, I need to search across all indexed columns in my table. I tried this:

```
CONTAINS(table.*, :value)
```

But I get:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException : Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MissingTokenException' was thrown. near line ... [select table.Id from Entities.Table table where CONTAINS(table.*,:p0) order by table.Id asc]
    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse()
    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Parse(Boolean isFilter)
    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)
    at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
    at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow)
    at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
```

So it would seem the HQL parser chokes on the asterisk. I thought of doing this:

```
CONTAINS(table.Column1, :value) or CONTAINS(table.Column2, :value)
```

Not only is this inefficient, it can also yields incorrect results depending on the full text predicate in `:value`.

I tried customizing my dialect as per [these instructions](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx), but that doesn't help because you're still left with the same problem: specifying `table.*` causes the HQL parser to fall over.

I thought of specifying query substitutions:

```
<property name="query.substitutions">TABLECONTAINS(=CONTAINS(table.*,</property>
```

And then simply doing:

```
TABLECONTAINS(:value)
```

But that does not work. I'm not sure why - judging by the resultant error, the substitution just doesn't take place because "TABLECONTAINS" is still present in the query. Besides, this wouldn't work for all cases because I'd need to know the alias of the table and dynamically substitute it in.

Therefore, I rolled an interception-based approach:

```
using System;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.SqlCommand;

public class ContainsInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var indexOfTableContains = sql.IndexOfCaseInsensitive("TABLECONTAINS(");

        if (indexOfTableContains != -1)
        {
            var sqlPart = sql.ToString();
            var aliasIndex = sqlPart.LastIndexOf("Table ", indexOfTableContains, StringComparison.Ordinal);

            if (aliasIndex == -1)
            {
                return sql;
            }

            aliasIndex += "Table ".Length;
            var alias = sqlPart.Substring(aliasIndex, sqlPart.IndexOf(" ", aliasIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) - aliasIndex);
            sql = sql.Replace("TABLECONTAINS(", "CONTAINS(" + alias + ".*,");
        }

        return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

This works and I will now be able to sleep tonight, but I do feel a sudden desire to attend London's impending papal procession and shout out a confession.

Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a custom dialect would be the appropriate way to handle this. You can find some guidance in [this article](http://nhibernate.info/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx). I've used this approach to register SQL Server-specific functions like ISNULL for use in our projects.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not help (tried this too but forgot to put in my question). Basically, you're still left with the same problem. If I want to specify all columns in the table, I need to write `contains(table.*, :term)`, but the HQL parser chokes on that. Updating my question...

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you registered a function including the tablename and the .* property directly. Obviously you would need a seperate registration for each table, but that should (in theory) still cut down on the repetition quite a bit....

Comment: Hmmm...also noticed that hibernate supports escape sequences for hql (example at: http://www.coderanch.com/t/441409/ORM/java/Special-characters-hql) - not sure if NHib allows for this, though...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an ISQLQuery instead?

You can still retrieve entities, see http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-creating

Comment: Thanks, but wish it was that simple. Two problems with this: my code would explode in complexity, especially the code I have to do paging and sorting. The criteria API was a boon to getting that code succinct and maintainable. Secondly, the queries need to run against multiple DBs (SQL Server and SQLite). But wait - how can I run a full-text query against SQLite? I don't. The full-text predicate is dictated by user filters. If the filter includes a text predicate, I'll have to use SQL Server, otherwise I might get away with SQLite (cache). This happens transparently to the query code.